# ui-view rendering main template twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, view, angular-ui-router

Im using anugularJS and for some reason the main template is being rendered twice when i use ui-view.

This does not make sense to me. also, for some reason, when i state my url's in app.js, if i add a '`/`' in the retern state, the url has two '`/`' when the button to add the second template is clicked and the url no longer works. heres my code: index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="searchAppApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">searchApp</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular
  .module('searchAppApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl as main'
    })
    .state("home.results", {
      url: 'results',
      templateUrl: 'views/results.html'
    });
  }])
```

main template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <h1 id="title">SearchApp</h1>
    <h4 id="subtitle">Find local spots in your area</h4>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="searchApp">
    <div id="placeId">
      <p class="fa fa-map-o"></p>
      <input id="placeInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter a place"></input>
      <input id="distanceInput" type="text" placeholder="Search radius (miles)"></input>
      <select id="selectCategories">
        <option>Search Categories</option>
      </select>
          <p><a ui-sref=".results">Submit</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ui-view></ui-view>
```

results template is currently pretty much blank, i just have a simple

statement to show it appeared alright.

Comment: So you makes `ng-include='views/main.html'` that contains `ui-view` inside. And because of routes config `ui-view` should be filled with `'views/main.html'` again. Works as expected. It could be better once you replace `ng-include` with `ui-view` in your index.html

Comment: hey, im sorry im a little confused by your answer, would you mind writing out the code snippets that i would need to add/replace? thanks! @skyboyer

Comment: Alex Berman, sorry, I missed the point you are using nested states. Ignore my comment.

Comment: A little old question, but did you even find what caused this? I think I have the same problem after upgrading my libraries...

Comment: For me, it seems to be caused by the upgrade of JQuery from 3.4.1 to 3.5.1. Not sure what the fix is...

Comment: I see this in your code, which seems wrong though: `<div ui-view></ui-view>`.

Comment: OK. For me, changing a directive attribute from this : `<i data-directive/>` to this: `<i data-directive></i>` fixed it. Stupid HTML language... Not sure how JQuery was involved in this as well...